# Return count() from Cypher pattern comprehension

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to return `count()` from Cypher pattern comprehension ?

The following query doesn't work:

```
[ (:Vacancy)<-[rpp:POTENTIAL_PROFILE]-(childD) | count(rpp) ] AS potentialJobablesCount
```

with the following error:

```
Aggregation column contains implicit grouping expressions. For example, in 'RETURN n.a, n.a + n.b + count(*)' the aggregation expression 'n.a + n.b + count(*)' includes the implicit grouping key 'n.b'. It may be possible to rewrite the query by extracting these grouping/aggregation expressions into a preceding WITH clause. Illegal expression(s): rpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation functions like `COUNT` can only be used in `WITH` and `RETURN` clauses.

But starting with neo4j 5.0 you can use the new [COUNT subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/subqueries/count/#:%7E:text=COUNT%20subquery%20with%20a%20UNION,not%20require%20the%20RETURN%20clause.). For example:

```
MATCH (childD:ChildD {id:123})
RETURN COUNT { (:Vacancy)<-[:POTENTIAL_PROFILE]-(childD) } AS potentialJobablesCount
```